# PDF from a dynamic page not downloading

Tags: android, download, android-webview

I have one dynamic page, that is like http://somesite.com/letters/pages/document.jsf,
that contains a .pdf file,
when I loaded this page in android native browser, I saw this in log -

```
03-25 19:30:50.421: V/BrowserActivity LOG(22302):  BrowserActivity onDownloadStart() Begin - url http://somesite.com/letters/pages/document.jsf contentDisposition - attachment: filename=Letter.pdf mimetype - application/pdf
```

I want to download this '**Letter.pdf'** which is an attachment as android log says, I have implemented downloadListener with a DefaultHTTPClient, but it downloads document.jsf page instead of that .pdf.

Please let me know what part of code I need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a very specific way of handling downloads.  Namely it hands off the download request to the Android DownloadManager, which basically sends off a second request based on the first.

More details here: http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/